# My python code only return second element in the list. How to correct it?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? It only returns the second element of the list.

I'm working on [LeetCode problem 720. Longest Word in Dictionary](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-word-in-dictionary/).

> Given an array of strings words representing an English Dictionary, return the longest word in words that can be built one character at a time by other words in words.
>
> If there is more than one possible answer, return the longest word with the smallest lexicographical order. If there is no answer, return the empty string.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Input: `words = ["w","wo","wor","worl","world"]`
>
> Output: `"world"`
>
> Explanation: The word "world" can be built one character at a time by "w", "wo", "wor", and "worl".
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> Input: `words = ["a","banana","app","appl","ap","apply","apple"]`
>
> Output: `"apple"`
>
> Explanation: Both "apply" and "apple" can be built from other words in the dictionary. However, "apple" is lexicographically smaller than "apply".

This is my code so far:

```
class Solution:
    def longestWord(self, words: List[str]) -> str:
        words.sort(key=len)
    
        def find(m,n):
            
            if n==0 and len(words[n])!=1:
                return Flase
            if len(words[n])==1:
                return 1
                
            if words[m]==words[n]+words[m][-1]:
                result=find(n,n-1)
            else:
                n=n-1
                result=find(m,n)
        
        for i in range(len(words)-1,0,-1):
            j=i-1
            
            res=find(i,j)
            
            if res==1:
                
                return words[i]
        
        return ''
```

Comment: This code has obvious errors, such as `return Flase`.  Please post code that actually runs...

Comment: Your input
["w","wo","wor","worl","world"]
Output
"wo"
Expected
"world"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                           ----------------------- It runs.

Comment: That's only because you never ran that `return` statement.  It IS an error.

Comment: You're setting `result=find(n,n-1)` and `result=find(m,n)`, but you never use `result`.  You need those to be `return` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "core" of your find function looks like this:

```
            if words[m]==words[n]+words[m][-1]:
                result=find(n,n-1)
            else:
                n=n-1
                result=find(m,n)
```

Replace that with this:

```
            if words[m]==words[n]+words[m][-1]:
                return find(n,n-1)
            else:
                return False
```

That gets you closer, but there's still a problem: that returns the FIRST match, but not necessarily the smallest lexicographically.  For that, you'll need to change your `sort` key.